# J2OBJC javax connot be resolved

Tags: java, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to convert my java file to objective c file. My java file includes javax imports. When i am trying to convert wit J2OBJC i got the error "The import javax cannot be resolved". Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

It's already pretty though to run javax libraries on Android.
I think you would save ton of time refactoring your model and eliminating the direct dependency over the javax libraries. 
Then you can use j2objc to convert the plain model without the javax dependecies.